# Did the kohanim physically carry the aron?

Tags: mishkan-tabernacle, ark-aron-kodesh, parashat-teruma, gold

The Chizkuni (Shemos 25:11) [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.25.11?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Chizkuni%2C_Exodus.25.11.1&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en)

> וצפית אתו זהב ראוי היה הארון להיות כולו של זהב אלא שלא יהא כבד לנשאו,
> ודינו להנשא בכתף כדכתיב כי עבודת הקדש עליהם בכתף ישאו, וכן מצינו במזבח
> שהיה נבוב לחות כדי שלא יהא כבד. - The ark was actually
> designed to be constructed completely of pure gold, but it would have
> been too heavy to carry, especially since the Torah had commanded the
> sons of Kehat to carry it on their shoulders. Compare Numbers 7,9. We
> find that the altar was also hollow and filled with earth, presumably
> for the same consideration. (Exodus 27,8)

Yet the Gemara [Sotah (35a)](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.35a.15?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi) explains

> נמצא ארון ונושאיו וכהנים מצד אחד וישראל מצד אחד נשא ארון את נושאיו
> ועבר שנאמר (יהושע ד, יא) ויהי כאשר תם כל העם לעבור ויעבור ארון ה'
> והכהנים לפני העם -  It follows that the Ark and its bearers and the
> priests were on one side of the Jordan, the east side, and the rest of
> the Jewish people were on the other side, the west side. Subsequently,
> the Ark carried its bearers in the air and crossed the Jordan, as it
> is stated: “When all the people were completely passed over, the Ark
> of the Lord passed on, and the priests, before the people” (Joshua
> 4:11).

Why would it make a difference whether the aron was heavy to be made completely of gold if it would carry its bearers?

Comment: Did it always carry its bearers?

Comment: אין סומכים על הנס?

Comment: The sons of Kehat who carried the ark are (non-kehuna) Levim

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91_%D7%9C%D7%94_%D7%92 וַיֹּאמֶר לַלְוִיִּם המבונים [הַמְּבִינִים] לְכָל יִשְׂרָאֵל הַקְּדוֹשִׁים לַיהוָה תְּנוּ אֶת אֲרוֹן הַקֹּדֶשׁ בַּבַּיִת אֲשֶׁר בָּנָה שְׁלֹמֹה בֶן דָּוִיד מֶלֶךְ יִשְׂרָאֵל אֵין לָכֶם מַשָּׂא בַּכָּתֵף עַתָּה עִבְדוּ אֶת יְהוָה אֱלֹהֵיכֶם וְאֵת עַמּוֹ יִשְׂרָאֵל Also implies the *aron* was carried.

Comment: @JoelK True, but this is Hashem telling us how to build the aron, not us constructing the blueprints of how to build a more portable box

Comment: @DoubleAA Good point, though that Gemara later on seems to say it does carry its bearers at least on a consistent basis: וישלח עוזא את ידו לאחוז את הארון אמר לו הקב"ה עוזא נושאיו נשא עצמו לא כל שכן